# (Discord.js v12) Getting embed colors from different file

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed

Hey Im having trouble inserting colours from a different file into my command file. If i don't make sense I apologize.

Here is my code in my command file and embed.json colour file

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const color = require('./config/embed.json');
module.exports = {
        name: "developer",
        cooldown: 10,
        aliases: "dev",
        
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
const dev = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(color.blue)
    .setTitle('Example Dev name')
    .setAuthor(`${message.author.username}`, `${message.author.displayAvatarURL()}`)
    .setDescription('Hello I am Dve lmao')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Dev: Developer');

message.channel.send(dev);
    }
};
```

And my embed.json file is

```
{
  "green": "",
  "blue": "#5865f2",
  "red": ""
}
```

Comment: ```error: cannot find module './config/embed.json'```                     is the error

Comment: So the path is incorrect.

Comment: When you require the file, it is looking for a folder named `config` in the same folder as your command file and then looking for a file named `embed.json` in that `config` folder. If you have stored the file anywhere else, you need to give the correct filepath for that

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/RTkKDV7) Is my files, how would I require embed.json in developer.js ?

Comment: `../../config/embed.json`